# JS: Add/remove element from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to add/remove an element to/from an array depending on an boolean value. This is what is working.

Is it possible to make this a bit shorter?

```
if (state === true) {
    const index = array.indexOf(id)
    if (index > -1)
        array.splice(index, 1)
}
if (state === false) {
    const index = array.indexOf(id)
    if (index === -1)
        array.push(id)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortened & simplified.

```js
const index = array.indexOf(id);

if (state === true && index > -1) {
  array.splice(index, 1)
} else if (state === false && index === -1)  {
  array.push(id)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit shorter:

```
const index = array.indexOf(id);

if (state === true && index > -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
} else if (state === false && index === -1) {
    array.push(id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) with checking state, depending of the function.

In the first part push only if `state` is falsy and in the second part splice only if `state` is truthy.

```
const index = array.indexOf(id);
index === -1 ? state || array.push(id) : state && array.splice(index, 1);
```

Table of truth

> ```
> index  state  index === -1 ? state || array.push(id) : state && array.splice(index, 1)
> -----  -----  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>    -1   true        true      true
>    -1   false       true      false   array.push(id)
> !==-1   true       false                                true    array.splice(index, 1)
> !==-1   false      false                               false
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
const index = array.indexOf(id);

//condition           ? condition true         : condition false
(state && index > -1) ? array.splice(index, 1) : array.push(id);
```

This is using a [shortened conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
There is a handy list of some [JavaScript Shorthands here](https://www.sitepoint.com/shorthand-javascript-techniques/)

Comment: no. actually you miss the part where no splice and pushing has to take place.

Comment: @NinaScholz that would be this part - `: array.push(id);`

Comment: @NinaScholz can you explain why you think Im missing the push?

Comment: you may have a look to [my table of truth](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42395183/1447675), there are 4 possibilites and you just have one in the check and leave the three others as one.

Comment: @NinaScholz Fair enough, I misunderstood your original comment, ironically you should have written **or** instead of **and**.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following short approach:

```
const index = array.indexOf(id);
if (typeof state === 'boolean') {  // considering only boolean values for `state`
    (state && index > -1 && array.splice(index, 1)) || (!state && index === -1 && array.push(id));
}
```